# How to access files from a subfolder that lies into a folder which recently created or modified using python?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I am performing web test automation using selenium Webdriver. I am pretty much new to python and Web test. The question is : **I want to write a Python code that automatically opens the files in following way:**

"C:\Software\" this path has many folders like

```
C:\Software\ 
          AB_101_B1\
                AB_101_B1\
                    *.bin
                    *.hex
                    *.hex
                AB_101_B1.zip

          AB_101_B2\
               AB_101_B2\
                   *.bin
                   *.hex
                   *.hex
               AB_101_B2.zip

          AB_102_B1\
               AB_102_B1\
                   *.bin
                   *.hex
                   *.hex
               AB_102_B1.zip
          ...

         AB_103_B7\
               AB_103_B7\
                   *.bin
                   *.hex
                   *.hex
               AB_103_B1.zip
```

Here **AB_103_B7** is latest created or modified folder. Each folder contains one subfolder with same name as main folder(eg:AB_103_B7) and one ZIP folder (AB_103_B7.zip). The subfolder and ZIP folder contains 3 files with different extensions(Example: .bin, .hex , .hex)

**I want to access latest modified or created folder then automatically upload files from this subfolder and also upload zip folder into Website.**

Note: The main folder "**AB_*** " keeps updating. So code must detect the latest folder either by name or by modified time.
I could directly upload file by setting directory, Example: `driver.find_element_by_id('abc').send_keys("C:\software\AB_103_B7\AB_103_B7\test.bin")`.
But my problem is to access the latest folder.

Could any help me with coding in python? I checked `os.walk()` from other questions. I am confused about what should be written for **dirname, subdirs, files**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding most recently edited file in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731014/finding-most-recently-edited-file-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! As I said i have been through example of os.walk() but did not understood how i must frame it in my question. For example what is to be dirname,subdirs,files in os.walk(".").

Comment: `dirname`- path to folder (string), `subdirs`- all subfolder names of `dirname` (list), `files`- names of files located inside `dirname` (list). `"."` means current directory. To make it clear, just run `for dirname,subdirs,files in os.walk("C:\Software"): print(dirname,subdirs,files)`

Comment: `os.walk()` is a generator object. `dirname, subdirs, files` are just variables for your loop. You can call them `i, j, k` or whatever... `os.walk` has one parameter- path to folder, so you need to send path to your root folder as argument and `os.walk` will recursively iterate through all of its subfolders

Comment: I was making mistake of giving path to dirname and os.walk as os.walk('.'). Finally!! It solved my problem! Thank you.

Comment: Now the problem is according to the program max_dir = C:\Software\latestfolder and max_file = latestfolder.zip but i also want to access those .bin,.hex files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and let me know in case of any issues:

```
import os
path = "C:\\Software\\"
latest_modified_folder = ''
time_of_modification = 0

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for subdir in subdirs:
        if os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, subdir)) > time_of_modification:
            time_of_modification = os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, subdir))
            latest_modified_folder = os.path.join(root, subdir)

for file_ in os.listdir(latest_modified_folder):
    # I'm not sure about how you want to upload all files from folder, so...
    driver.find_element_by_id('abc').send_keys(os.path.join(latest_modified_folder, file_))
```